# What's the most efficient way to code a multiple step Post Route? NodeJS, Express, Mongo, IPFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ipfs

I'm working on a project and I have a post route written basically like this:

```js
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    if (req.session.loggedIn && req.files) {
//append user entered name to reflect appropriate file extension
        let ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name)
        req.files.file.name = req.body.filename + ext;

// Take all the req data and declare for later use
        const file = req.files.file
        const fileName = file.name;
        const authKey = req.session.authKey;
        const content = req.body.content
        const fileTags = req.body.tags;
        const filePath = '/tmp/' + fileName;

//Copy file from req to the server into 'uploads' folder     
        file.mv('./uploads/' + fileName, function(err) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            return emitter.emit('moved')
        })

        let baseFile = path.join('./uploads', path.basename(filePath));
        console.log(`BASEFILE: ${baseFile}`)
//Encrypt File from 'uploads' (the encrypt function outputs to 'tmp' directory on server
        emitter.on('moved', async function() {
                console.log(`File has been moved, Encrypting ${baseFile} now.`)
                await encrypt({ file: baseFile, password: authKey })
                return emitter.emit('encrypted')
            })
//Erase upload file from server
        emitter.on('Yoo Hoo Clean Up!!', function() {
            console.log('Erasing Base File')
            cleanUp(baseFile)
            emitter.emit('respond')
        })

// Add Pertinent info to MongoDB for retrieving the file later
        emitter.on('ipfs-complete', async function dbWriteFile(fileHash) {
            console.log('Adding to Database')
            await db.IPFS.create({ owner: db.User._id, title: fileName, content: content, dbCID: fileHash, tags: fileTags })
                .then((file) => {
                    console.log(`New IPFS FILE: ${file}`);
                    emitter.emit('Yoo Hoo Clean Up!!')

                })
        })

//Add File to IPFS remote Node and return the hash of the file
        emitter.on('encrypted', async function() {
            console.log('Adding to IPFS')
            let tmpFile = `${fileName}.enc`
            let tmpPath = path.join('./tmp/', tmpFile)
            console.log(`tmpFile: ${tmpFile}`)
            console.log(`tmpPath PARSE: ${tmpPath}`)
            const fileHash = await addFile(`./${tmpFile}`, tmpPath)
            return emitter.emit('ipfs-complete', fileHash)

        })


        emitter.on('respond', function() {
            res.redirect('/recap')
        })
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: `Bad Request received check your request again, bruh.` })
    }
})
```

A few things to note:

1. Each function (move file, encrypt file, add to IPFS, write to database) works perfectly when executed separately, but when I attempt to run them all together, the "file" uploaded to IPFS always returns a size of 6 bytes with the same hash.
2. The emitter events were my most recent attempt to try and force an order (terribly unsuccessful)
   2a. I apologize for my code being absolute trash, but I've been working at this for days and kinda gave up on keeping it pretty, but I will refactor and prettify it once I figure this out.

3.I'm fairly new to coding, so this could be (and probably is) something dumb. I acknowledge this and truly appreciate any help I can get.

4. If anyone is kind enough to help me out, but needs more code (i.e. what the addFile() or encrypt() looks like), I am more than happy to share more.

Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions/instructions/criticisms.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, basically I needed to call the `addFile()` as a callback of `encrypt()` and pass in the `writestream.path` as the arguments.